# Retrieve a list value from request jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
<%
        if(tableauData != null && tableauData.size() > 0 ) {
        for (int i=0;i<tableauData.size();i++) {
        Tableaujs tableaujs = (Tableaujs)tableauData.elementAt(i);
    %>

    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"> <%=tableaujs.getColonne()%> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"> <magl:champTexte _nom="taux" valeur="<%=tableaujs.getTaux().toString()%>"  _size="3" _editable="true" /> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"> <magl:listeMultiChamps _nom="fcwc06e0TableauDataItems"
            valeursInitiales="true" monospace="false" size="1">

            <magl:champListe _nom="liblidc" _size="30" />
            </magl:listeMultiChamps>
             </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"> </td>
    </tr>

    <% } 
    }   
    %>
```

I need to fetch the entire list of `tableaujs.getColonne()` on submit. When I do `request.getParameter(taux)`, I just get one column value. How can I fetch the entire list from request.

Comment: please post complete code where you are retrieving data and the html/jsp page which submits the data.

Comment: So you're fetching a list from DB or somewhere and displaying it in a table and doing some changes in value (I hope so), finally you need to submit all the values whatever in the table. Am I correct?

Comment: yes.. i need to capture the modified value by the user